# Вытащить несколько значений из регулярки C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как извлечь регуляркой несколько значений в C# скажем из такой (\d+)\"(\d+)

Слегка запутался в документации, понятно что первая группа - число и вторая тоже, но то что у меня сейчас выходит это строка, где справа число разделитель и слева число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у `Match` есть поле `Groups`: `Groups[0]` - вся совпадающая строка, `Groups[1..n]` - группы

или я не правильно понял вопрос?